Polymorphism of Address Model in Laravel
Given I have the three Models User, Venue and Address (example taken from Address - Polymorphic association).

A User has one Address.
A Venue has one Address.
A User/Venue may use the same address, so an Address is used by several Models (User|Venue|...)

I'd like to implement this in Laravel, but I am not sure which relation type I need to use.
At first a polymorphic one-to-many seems correct:
class Address extends Model
{
    public function addressable(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class User extends Model // Venue is identical
{
    public function address(): MorphOne
    {
        return $this->morphOne(Address::class);
    }
}

With this, I'm able to retrieve the address by calling $user->address and $venue->address. But the other way round I can only access one single addressable by $address->addressable.
Am I wrong and this is actually a polymorphic many-to-many relation?
